# Whats the quickest and most secure way to write form data to a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I am looking to store data from a form in a mysql database and being new to this I would like to do this in a fairly easy way using PHP but I don't want the form hacked by everyone the first day its out there :-)

This is not credit card info, in fact if anyone read it, it would not matter at all but I still would like to stop bad data and people adding form entries if that were possible.

I imagine most online apps have a basic level of security and being new I am worried I fail to put that in place.

Comment: You might want to refine where you think your weak spot is? Do you fear clients sending bad data? Do you fear a man-in-the-middle sniffing the form data? Or perhaps you fear someone gaining access to your database server?

Comment: SSL Maybe something you want to look into, depending on the site and data being transmitted. It can cost money (if you do a non-self signed), but it would encrypt the data being sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some basic rules you have to apply.

1. Validate the user input on the client side (not really needed, but nice for the user)
2. Validate the user input on the server side
3. Sanitize the user's input using for example `mysql_real_escape_string` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php
4. insert data in mysql